# Ruby on rails Installation error not able to install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I downloaded rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p247 and DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx 
Follow all the steps from https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

I am getting following error:-

ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]

```
C:\Users\NISHA>cd ..

C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd Ruby200

C:\Ruby200>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Ruby200>gems -v
'gems' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Ruby200>cd..

C:\>cd Devkit

C:\Devkit>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.0.0 at C:/Ruby200

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

C:\Devkit>ruby dk.rb review
Based upon the settings in the 'config.yml' file generated
from running 'ruby dk.rb init' and any of your customizations,
DevKit functionality will be injected into the following Rubies
when you run 'ruby dk.rb install'.

C:/Ruby200

C:\Devkit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby200'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'

C:\Devkit>rails -v
'rails' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can any one Please help me into this.

Comment: Use `gem` command to manage gems.  You should use `gem install rails` to install gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have `rubygems` installed, which is the remit of [devkit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/)

There is a [good tutorial here](https://forwardhq.com/support/installing-ruby-windows)

I think your error is because you're using `gems` in command line. Try using `gem -v` and you'll see that it will work. If you use the singular `gem`, you can then fire `gem install rails`, to get it so you're able to install `rails` directly

Comment: Getting Error : DL is deprecated Please use Fiddle

Comment: That's common - does it stop after this, or keep going?

Comment: I used command gem install forward It gave me the result 4 gems installed.Then I used the command gem install rail.. then when I am running command rails -v Now it shows me the version of rails Rails 4.1.0 with additional line DL is deprecated, Please use Fiddle.What is this line?? I am not able to start rail server.